# How to make squared patches on a shape smooth?

Tags: raytracing

I'm implementing area light in my ray tracer. In a simple sphere obj model (i.e. it's the sphere that consists of triangles) squared patches are displayed. How can I make sphere surface smooth?

I suspect that surface normals calculation must be fixed.

Currently for each triangle single normal is computed for all points it contains.

Here's the sphere:

[image: sphere]

Answer (score 0):

The square patches are displayed because you are simply seeing the triangles that make up the obj model. Either find an obj model with more triangles or use texture mapping to smooth the surface. If you are looking for a computationally effective method for drawing spheres, you can create a collision algorithm for spheres. I do not know how low-level you went on your ray-tracing project, but if you defined the reflection algorithm for the triangle, you can pretty easily do one for a sphere. I have created a visualization here:

https://www.geogebra.org/m/g9rrhttp

You can check that out if you want. If you do not want to implement this new algorithm, you can look for an obj model with a texture. the texture is what will make it appear smooth.